# Jquery Variable - get name attribute and oben div with id of same name attribute

Tags: jquery, variables

i have some problem. I have a list with anchors inside the `li`'s. now when the user `click` one anchor i want to safe the "`name`" attribute of the anchor and load content from a `div` with the "`id`" of the anchors "`name`". So anchors "`name`" attribute and `div`'s "`id`" attribute are the same.

So that work for me:

```
<ul>
    <li><a name="AnchorId"</li>
</ul>
<div id="AnchorId"></div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#element li a').click(function(e){   
    e.preventDefault();     
    var currentName = $(this).attr('name'); // <--- Get the name in plain       

    $('#element2').fadeOut("fast",loadContent);     


    var Content = $("#AnchroId").html(); // <-- problem with insert

    function loadContent() {            
        $('#element2').html(Content);       
        $('#element2').fadeIn("normal");
    }
});
```

Problem is when i try ti change the "`#AnchroId`" above with the variable currentName that i read before. that dont work. when i put in the plain id it worked. and also the currentName im getting right with `$(this).attr('name')`.

So guys how can i perfomr this: `var Content = $(VARIABLE currentName).html();`

??

thx guxs

Comment: show your html as well

Comment: Choose the answer below as "Correct" to help people looking for similar solution.

Comment: i did - sorry i forgot ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a simple concatenation operation

```
var Content = $('#' + currentName).html();
```

Hope it helps